# AS3 - Endless Vertically Scrolling Background

Tags: actionscript-3, scroll, background, flashdevelop

As my first AS3 project, I'm developing a simple space shooter/bullet hell game. I looked online for a way of producing an infinite background scrolling effect and found this working code.

```
    public function backgroundScroll (evt:Event):void
    {
        background1.y -= scrollspeed;
        background2.y -= scrollspeed;
        if (background1.y <= -background2.height)
        {               
            background1.y = background2.y + background2.height;
        }
        else if (background2.y <= -background2.height)
        {
            background2.y = background1.y + background1.height;
        }           
    }
```

This causes the background to infinitely scroll upwards from the bottom of the screen without fail, but no matter what I try, I cannot cause it to instead infinitely scroll down from the top of the screen. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Code seems to be works fine, i think you have some trubles with names and with events.

How is code working :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l0t9.png)

Make sure that :

1) You have add ENTER_FRAME listener

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, backgroundScroll );
```

2) background1 & background1 is names of objects, that you need

Comment: How does this answer the question how to make it scroll down?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have two backgrounds that are larger than the height of your stage (so they would switch when the are going off-screen at the bottom. Note that the "- background1.height" parts have changed as well

```
// at the beginning you set the backgrounds one below another
background1.y = 0;
background2.y = background1.height;

public function backgroundScroll (evt:Event):void
{
    background1.y += scrollspeed;
    background2.y += scrollspeed;

    if (background1.y >= stage.stageHeight)
    {        
        // the background is below the visible stage area, put it above the other background       
        background1.y = background2.y - background1.height;
    }
    else if (background2.y >= stage.stageHeight)
    {
        background2.y = background1.y - background2.height;
    }           
}
```

Comment: This is something I tried before, and what that did was cause the background to just scroll of the screen and leave the default white space behind.

Comment: Oh right, the "-background.height" parts need to change as well - I've edited my solution. And now the script checks against the visible stage height